# No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_REDUCES Titan ver 0.5.1

Tags: hadoop, gremlin, titan

Hi I've installed the latest Titan graph Database ver. 0.5.1

I have hadoop ver.2.5.1 with hbase 0.98.5 and elastic-search ver.1.3.2

All off this are running on Mac OS X 10.9.5
with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

I'm trying to run this [examples](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.1/hadoop-getting-started.html)

I receive the following error:

> 15:20:30 ERROR com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.config.HBaseAuthHelper 
>   - Not obtaining HBase Auth Token for MapReduce job VerticesMap.Map 15:20:31 WARN 
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.compat.h2.Hadoop2Compiler  - Path
>   tracking is enabled for this Titan/Hadoop job (space and time
>   expensive) 15:20:31 WARN 
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.compat.h2.Hadoop2Compiler  - State
>   tracking is enabled for this Titan/Hadoop job (full deletes not
>   possible) 15:20:31 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  -
>   Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool
>   interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
>   15:20:32 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat 
>   - Total input paths to process : 1 15:20:32 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - number of splits:1
>   15:20:32 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Submitting
>   tokens for job: job_1413201045775_0008 15:20:32 INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - The url to track the job:
>   15:20:32 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Running job:
>   job_1413201045775_0008 15:20:40 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job 
>   - Job job_1413201045775_0008 running in uber mode : false 15:20:40 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 0% reduce 0% 15:20:52
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 0% 15:20:59
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 100%
>   15:21:00 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job
>   job_1413201045775_0008 completed successfully No enum constant
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_REDUCES

Ca someone help me with this error. I have installed titan 0.5.0 and it worked OK

Thanks